# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. Laravel 5.6?

Tags: laravel, installation, laravel-5.6, updating

Here is the screenshot of the CMD

[image]
**Error message in CMD:**

> Problem 1
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.29
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.28
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.27
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.26
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.25
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.24
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.23
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.22
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.21
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.20
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.19
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.18
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.17
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.16
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.15
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.14
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.13
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.12
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.11
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.10
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.9
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.8
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.7
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.6
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.5
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.4
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.2
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.1
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.1.3
>       - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.6.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12,
>   v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.18, v5.6.19, v5.6.2,
>   v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26,
>   v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7,
>   v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
>       - Conclusion: don't install phpspec/phpspec 2.5.8
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.0.1|install phpspec/phpspec 2.5.8
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.0.2|install phpspec/phpspec 2.5.8
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.0.3|install phpspec/phpspec 2.5.8
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.0.4|install phpspec/phpspec 2.5.8
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.0.5|install phpspec/phpspec 2.5.8
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.0.6|install phpspec/phpspec 2.5.8
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.0.7|install phpspec/phpspec 2.5.8
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.0.8|install phpspec/phpspec 2.5.8
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.0.9|install phpspec/phpspec 2.5.8
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.0.10|install phpspec/phpspec 2.5.8
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.0.11|install phpspec/phpspec 2.5.8
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.0.12|install phpspec/phpspec 2.5.8
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.0.13|install phpspec/phpspec 2.5.8
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.0.14|install phpspec/phpspec 2.5.8
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.1.0|install phpspec/phpspec 2.5.8
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.1.1|install phpspec/phpspec 2.5.8
>
> ```
> - laravel/framework v5.6.0 requires symfony/process ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.11,
> ```
>
> v4.0.12, v4.0.13, v4.0.14, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6,
>   v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.2, v4.1.3].
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.1.2|install phpspec/phpspec 2.5.8
>       - Installation request for phpspec/phpspec ~2.1 -> satisfiable by phpspec/phpspec[2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.3.0, 2.4.0, 2.4.1,
>   2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.5.4, 2.5.5, 2.5.6, 2.5.7, 2.5.8].

**My composure:**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

How can I update to **Laravel 5.6** ?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Can't upgrade from laravel 5.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to remove **composer.lock file** + **vendor folder**

and run `composer install` again

Comment: Hi @maulik i am facing the same issue when i am trying to upgrade laravel version from 5.2.45 to 5.4. I have question in the solution given by you is "My project is existing and in that already many packages installed so that all will be removed? And that will be be impact on the website?