# Upgrade Laravel version from 5.2.45 to 5.4

Tags: laravel

I am working on an existing application and the application is in laravel framework(`version 5.2.45`).And now i have to upgrade it to the version(`5.4`).I have follow the upgrade version step from laravel official documentation. Below is the steps which i have done :

1) Update the version number in laravel `composer.json` file in "`laravel/framework`" key.

2) Then after run the command `composer update`.

3) After that during executing the command i face error and the solution of that is to add the below line in `composer.json` file.

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
```

4) Then after again i execute the command `composer update`.Now i am facing the issue which i have attached in the below image :

[image]

Here is the code of composer.json file :

```
    {
  "name": "ozdemirburak/laravel-5-simple-cms",
  "description": "Simple Laravel 5 content management system for starters.",
  "keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel",
    "cms"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*",
    "baum/baum": "~1.1",
    "kris/laravel-form-builder": "1.6.*",
    "laracasts/flash": "~1.3",
    "mews/purifier": "~2.0",
    "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "~3.1.4",
    "barryvdh/laravel-elfinder": "0.3.*",
    "spatie/laravel-analytics": "~1.1",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~6.0",
    "pingpong/modules": "~2.1",
    "caffeinated/menus": "~2.0",
    "fisharebest/laravel-assets": "~1.0",
    "caffeinated/themes": "2.0.5",
    "teepluss/theme": "dev-master",
    "roumen/sitemap": "2.6.*",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "^2.1",
    "intervention/image": "^2.3",
    "laravel/socialite": "^2.0",
    "xinax/laravel-gettext": "^3.1",
    "omnipay/paypal": " *",
    "mews/captcha": "^2.2"





  },
  "require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
    "doctrine/dbal": "~2.5",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~1.5",
    "laracasts/generators": "~1.1.3",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "~2.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "~2.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/",
      "Modules\\": "modules/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
      "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
      "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "php artisan clear-compiled",
      "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "php artisan clear-compiled",
      "php artisan optimize",
      "php artisan elfinder:publish"
    ]
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true,
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
  }
}
```

**Note : For the current error i also found a solution in the [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51648949/your-requirements-could-not-be-resolved-to-an-installable-set-of-packages-larav) and i implement that thing but still i am getting this error.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please share your composer.json file

Comment: Looks like you have conflicting packages in `composer.json`. Please share it.

Comment: @Sehdev Please check the question that i have updated.I have added code of "composer.json" file.

Answer (score 1):

You should update step by step, in your case update to 5.2 => 5.3 and after that 5.3 => 5.4 Please check laravel official documentation.

Comment: You are right. There are some very good explanations in the documentation how upgrade to newer versions and what you have to change eventually.

Comment: I have tried that trying to update version from 5.2 to 5.3 but in that also same issue occured.

Comment: @SohilChamadia please add error, if it possible with code note with screenahot

Comment: @VaheGalstyan Please check my question.I have mention already in that.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error output:

`"caffeinated/themes": "2.0.5"` is locked to Laravel 5.1/5.2.

Upgrade that first.

Then the rest should follow.

Comment: Can you please tell the process of upgrade the theme?

Comment: Update the version number.